# Want to select all the text when go on the react-select through tab button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am using the react-select [text](https://react-select.com/home)in my project, so I need whenever I go on the react-select through the tab button the selected value(means the text showing in the input) should be automatically highlighted itself or we can say select all the text.
For eg:-
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E78HV.png)

I tried to solve it with ref property but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.